# Attributed Value of Ternary Operator Resets After Each Loop

Tags: java, nested, operators, ternary

I would like to be able to go through an inputted string and count the amount of times "good" is written and compare it to how many times "bad" is written. If the good and the bad match, then goodVbad==0 and it returns true. Otherwise it returns false.

The code worked fine when I was using if statements inside the for-loop, but when using the ternary operator it doesn't. While debugging, I realized that each time the for-loop moves onto the next element 'goodVbad' becomes zero again. Kind of stumped, would love some advice. Thanks!

```
public static boolean goodbadClean(String word) {
    String [] wordS;
    int goodVbad=0;
    String good="good";
    String bad="bad";
    word=word.toLowerCase();
    word=word.replaceAll(good, " good ");
    word=word.replaceAll(bad, " bad ");
    wordS=word.split(" ");
    for(String i:wordS) {
        goodVbad=i.equals(good)?goodVbad++
                :i.equals(bad) ?goodVbad--
                :goodVbad;
    }
    if(goodVbad==0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `goodVbad=` in your `for` loop.  The `++` or `--` operations already assign the variable.  Don't try to do it again.  You're actually getting the pre-increment or pre-decrement value each time, which is why `goodVbad` ends up not changing.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provide an example of what the inputted string `word` could look like. If you need count the matches of the word, is one solution. If you are interested in counting repeated string _patterns_ is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the postfix `++` operator returns the *old* value, which you are assigning the variable, *then* increments. ie

```
goodVBad = goodVBad++;  // returns the old value, so does nothing
```

so you should use the prefixed `++` operator:

```
goodVBad = ++goodVBad; // increments first, returning the new value
```

But both of these are hard to read and brittle.

If you must use ternaries, change your code to:

```
goodVbad += i.equals(good) ? 1 : (i.equals(bad) ? -1 : 0);
```

However, nested ternaries are generally a style smell. I recommend instead:

```
if (i.equals(good)) {
    goodVBad++;
} else if (i.equals(bad)) {
    goodVBad--;
}
```

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem My bad. You're correct; from [the JSL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25): *The resulting boolean value is then used to choose either the second or the third operand expression:

If the value of the first operand is true, then the second operand expression is chosen.

If the value of the first operand is false, then the third operand expression is chosen.*

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem not enough coffee. see edits.

Comment: Cool.  I have replaced my downvote with an upvote.  I still think the simplest fix is just to get rid of `goodVbad =` at the beginning of the expression.  But I guess I could convert my comment under the question into an answer, if I could be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the OP needs to count the frequency of a string pattern in a given string, then you could do something like this with Java 8 or older:

```
public class CountMatches {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase1 = "goodbadbadgoodgoodbad"; // equal amount of good vs bad.
        String phrase2 = "goodbadbadgoodgoodbadbad"; // more bad than good.
        String phrase3 = "goodbadbadgoodgoodbadgood"; // more good than bad.

        // create capturing groups for "good" and "bad"
        String GOOD_REGEX = "(good)";
        String BAD_REGEX = "(bad)";

        Pattern gPattern = Pattern.compile(GOOD_REGEX);
        Pattern bPattern = Pattern.compile(BAD_REGEX);
        Matcher countGood = gPattern.matcher(phrase1);
        Matcher countBad = bPattern.matcher(phrase1);

        int count = 0;
        while (countBad.find()) {
            count--;
        }
        while (countGood.find()) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count == 0);
    }
}
```

With Java 9 or later:

```
public class CountMatches {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase1 = "goodbadbadgoodgoodbad"; // equal amount of good vs bad.
        String phrase2 = "goodbadbadgoodgoodbadbad"; // more bad than good.
        String phrase3 = "goodbadbadgoodgoodbadgood"; // more good than bad.

        String GOOD_REGEX = "(good)";
        String BAD_REGEX = "(bad)";

        Pattern gPattern = Pattern.compile(GOOD_REGEX);
        Pattern bPattern = Pattern.compile(BAD_REGEX);
        Matcher countGood = gPattern.matcher(phrase1);
        Matcher countBad = bPattern.matcher(phrase1);

        long cCount = countGood.results().count();
        long bCount = countBad.results().count();

        System.out.println(cCount - bCount == 0);
    }
}
```

My assumption is based on this line of code `word=word.replaceAll(good, " good ");`. This tells me that the expected input is something similar to the `phrase` variables I used for my testing.

By the way, this solution should work even if the words "good" and/or "bad" are preceded or followed by spaces.

UPDATE: Integrated looping to evaluate all expressions against all phrases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> expressions = List.of("(good)", "(bad)");
    List<String> phrases = List.of("goodbadbadgoodgoodbad", "goodbadbadgoodgoodbadbad", "goodbadbadgoodgoodbadgood", " good  bad     bad good   good bad ");

    for (String phrase : phrases) {
        List<Long> itemCount = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String regex : expressions) {
            Pattern gPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = gPattern.matcher(phrase);
            long count = matcher.results().count();
            System.out.println("Pattern \"" + regex + "\" appears " + count + (count == 1 ? " time" : " times"));
            itemCount.add(count);
        }
        long count = itemCount.stream().reduce((value1, value2) -> value1 - value2).get();
        System.out.println(count == 0);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Pattern "(good)" appears 3 times
Pattern "(bad)" appears 3 times
true
Pattern "(good)" appears 3 times
Pattern "(bad)" appears 4 times
false
Pattern "(good)" appears 4 times
Pattern "(bad)" appears 3 times
false
Pattern "(good)" appears 3 times
Pattern "(bad)" appears 3 times
true
```